# How to get previous build results in Sublime Text 3 (python)

Tags: python, build, sublimetext3

I did ctrl+b on a python file and it was supposed to take 2 hours for it to complete the run and display output. And it did run but then my computer restarted. Is there a way that I can access all the previous build results(ctrl+b outputs)?

Comment: Did you try **`Tools -> Build Results -> Show Build Results`**?

Comment: yes, but that just brings the output window back(which I had closed by pressing esc), what if I wanted to see the build result from the last time I did ctrl+b or 2 last to last time. I don't understand what is meaning of "show previous result?" coz it just says No more results?

Comment: as an eg: I run a simple print "hello boy" program and then I change it to "hello toy" and run again and "hello soy"; now if I want to see what was the previous build results how can I do that?

Comment: @Manoya figure this out? I don't think it is possible but just curious.